# Interpreting linear regression (Do grammar schools increase the attainment gap for disadvantaged pupils?)

Tags: interpretation, r-squared, f-statistic

On Monday The Education Policy Institute published its annual report on education in England https://epi.org.uk/annual-report-2023/. This focusses on the attainment gap between poorer pupils and their peers. Results are broken down for each of 150 local authorities. It was put to me that, "*It's clear most selective† LAs have a bigger gap than the norm.*" I was asked to find the supporting evidence. (†Selection is where children sit the "11+" entrance test to be admitted to academically focussed "grammar" schools.)

There are 150 Local Authorities in England. I created a continuous variable with the proportion of selective places in each authority. 115 of them have no selective school places at all. 35 have between just above zero and under 40%. I started by plotting (disadvantage ~ %selectiveness) using Seaborn’s regplot() and jointplot(). The trendline shows a *slight* positive correlation but the line is almost horizontal. I can’t see anything which could remotely be described as a pattern.
[image: Seaborn plots]

Using OLS regression on just the selective 35 LAs I have R-square **0.009** and F-statistic of **0.581**.

I think the correct interpretation is. R-square shows the resulting model explains less than one per cent of the actual results. F-statistic shows about a 6 in 10 chance that the predicted correlation is due to random variance in the data. Conclusion: There is no evidence of a correlation.

It has been a long time since I studied this formally and I’d really appreciate a second opinion before I revert to the person who asked.

I also tried OLS on the full 150. Improved F-statistic 0.404 but worse R-square 0.005.
I tried different transformations of the explanatory variable. I don’t think these are worth discussing because fundamentally the scatter plot looks as random as a Rorschach inkblot test.

Comment: You are right, there is no evidence of a linear association between the two variables.

Comment: The OLS results don't answer the question: "most ... than the norm" refers to *proportions* rather than means. The analysis it suggests is to compare the median gap for "selective" LAs (however that is defined) to the median gap for "the norm." One would do that by testing the hypothesis that the median gap for selective LAs is equal to or less than the median gap for *all other* LAs (thereby assuring the two groups being compared have no common data). A side-by-side pair of boxplots would be a good start for exploring this question. Consider jittering the scatterplot to resolve the overlaps!

Comment: Due to distribution of your independent variable it is a bit hard to judge, but are the residuals from OLS normally distributed? If not, does it impact the inference based on the F-statistic? Another question is, what is the confidence interval on your regression coefficient and what is a smallest practically  significant value of the regression coefficient. e.g.  if you have a regression coefficient 0.0001 and it is statistically significant, does it matter or would it make no difference in the real world?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helpful suggestions.
[Whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) suggests the original question is best addressed by comparing an experimental group of 35 ‘selective’ local authorities against a control group of local authorities with no selection starting with a boxplot.
[image: boxplot months disadvantage gap by selective and non-selective local authority]

I like to use a Kernel Density Estimation to produce a smoothed plot of the relative distributions. The area under the curve adds to 100%. Here are the two distributions, without shared variance so they can be compared with dotted lines showing the means.
[image: KDE disadvantage gap by selective and non-selective local authority]
Cohen (1969) suggests the following simple measure of Effect Size:
$$ \Delta = (\mu_e - \mu_c)/ \sigma $$
where $ \mu_e, \mu_c $ are the mean of the experimental group (selective authorities) and the control, and $ \sigma $ is the overall standard deviation. This gives me
$$ \Delta = (19.3 - 18.7)/ 521 = 0.125 \sigma $$

[Cryo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/275239/cryo) asks the valid question ‘So what?’ Expressed as months of lost education the difference between the two groups is 0.125σ where σ = 5.21 months.  This works out as about 20 days. In the context of disadvantaged children being almost 20 months behind their peers, this seems like the police pulling someone over for a faulty tail-light when they’re driving down the motorway playing the trombone.
Hedges and Olkin (1985) provide an objective measure of whether this effect size is significant.

$$ \Delta = \sqrt{\frac{(N_e+N_c)}{(N_e \times N_c)} +\frac{\Delta ^2}{2(N_e+N_c)} } $$
A 90% confidence interval for ∆ is
$$ \Delta - 1.64 \times \sigma [\Delta] {\text{ to }} \Delta + 1.64 \times \sigma [\Delta] $$
Calculating this in months results in a range (–1, +2.3) months which passes through zero so the results are not significant, even at 90%. :-/

**Linear regression.**
The linear regression equation for the gap in months is:
$$ gap=18.67 + 4.29 × pctsel $$
(Despite choice of name pctsel is the proportion ranging from 0 to 0.38 not the percentage.) The residuals are reasonably normally distributed with skew= *1.24 and kurtosis 0.69.
[image: Distribution of residuals]
The maximum difference between no selection at all and the most selective authority adds about (0.38 × 4.29 =) 1.6 months lost progress.
Coe (2002) provides the following rule of thumb: *“In the context of [English] secondary schools therefore, introducing a change in practice whose effect size was known to be 0.6 would result in an improvement of about a GCSE grade for each pupil in each subject.”* This suggests selection increases the attainment gap by about 1/5 of a grade across all subjects.

This is not to be dismissed, however there are other potential explanations. As the EPI observed, selective schools draw in high attaining non-disadvantaged children from other local authorities. These are then compared against the disadvantaged children from across that attainment distribution. (Andrews et al 2016.) Another approach would be to focus on the type of school and now which LA it happens to reside in but that is also problematic. When promoting increased selection PM Theresa May claimed “the attainment gap between rich and poor pupils is reduced to almost zero for children in selective schools.” (https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/britain-the-great-meritocracy-prime-ministers-speech) This is true, however the reason is simply because selective schools only admit children with high prior attainment.

Perhaps the last word should go to [Utobi](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/56940/utobi) – *nothing to see here*! A massive thanks to those who replied. I may have ended up answering my own question, but I’m not as confident with the statistics as I am with the subject matter. The help and suggestions were invaluable.

Andrews, J. Hutchison, J. Johnes, R. (2016) *Grammar schools and social mobility*. Education Policy Institute.

Coe, R. (2002) *It’s the effect size stupid!* Presented at the British Educational Research Association annual conference, Exeter

Cohen, J. (1969) *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*. NY: Academic Press.

Hedges, L. and Olkin, I. (1985) *Statistical Methods for Meta­Analysis*. New York: Academic Press.